# ImageDraw - adapt Font Size dynamically to text length

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The font size has to dynamically adapt to different the text length, which can vary a lot.
Currently I have a ton of code, basically manually checking how long the incoming text is and manually giving a font size for that.

There has to be a better solution. I don't think I can use `ImageDraw.textsize`.

Has anyone a solution for this kinda problem?

Comment: it is better to give a trial code, input, expected output then clarify the problem.

Comment: the only solution is `ImageDraw.textsize` and check different sizes. You can use `for`-loop for this or check two sizes and try to use these results to aproximate correct size.

Comment: I found `ImageDraw.textbbox` (in version 8.0.0) which can gives better results (it calculate top margin which you can't get with `ImageDraw.textsize`) but it still need the same method with `for`-loop to test different font sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know other method then `ImageDraw.textsize()` in `for`-loop which checks it for different font sizes.

Now I found that in version 8.0.0 they add `ImageDraw.textbbox()` which gives better results because it calculates also top margin which can be use to better calcualte position.

But it still needs `for`-loop to check it for different font sizes.

---

Result with `textsize`:

[image]

Result with `textbbox` (center vertically):

[image]

---

It is my example which calculate font size and box size to use it directly to calculate

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

width = 300
height = 100

text = "Hello World"

font_name = 'Ubuntu-M'

# --- create image for text ---

img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# --- calculate font size, box ---

# default values at start
font_size = None   # for font size
font = None        # for object truetype with correct font size
box = None         # for version 8.0.0

# test for different font sizes
for size in range(1, 500):

    # create new font
    new_font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, size)
    
    # calculate bbox for version 8.0.0
    new_box = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, new_font)  # need 8.0.0
    
    # `bbox` may have top/left margin so calculate real width/height
    new_w = new_box[2] - new_box[0]  # bottom-top
    new_h = new_box[3] - new_box[1]  # right-left
    #print(size, '|', new_w, new_h, '|', new_box)

    # if too big then exit with previous values
    if new_w > width or new_h > height:
        break
        
    # set new current values as current values
    font_size = size
    font = new_font
    box = new_box
    w = new_w
    h = new_h
    
# --- use it ---
    
print('font size:', font_size)
print('box:', box)

print('w <= width :', w, '<=', width)
print('h <= height:', h, '<=', height)

# calculate position (minus margins in box)
x = (width - w)//2 - box[0]   # minus left margin
y = (height - h)//2 - box[3]  # minus top margin
print('w,h (without margins):', w, h)
print('x,y (without margins):', x, y)

# draw it 
draw.text((x, y), text, (0, 0, 0), font)

# display result
img.show()

img.save('result-textbbox.png', 'png')
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same as function

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def get_font(img, text, font_name, width, height):
    # default values at start
    font_size = None   # for font size
    font = None        # for object truetype with correct font size
    box = None         # for version 8.0.0

    # test for different font sizes
    for size in range(1, 500):

        # create new font
        new_font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, size)

        # calculate bbox for version 8.0.0
        new_box = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, new_font)  # need 8.0.0

        # `bbox` may have top/left margin so calculate real width/height
        new_w = new_box[2] - new_box[0]  # bottom-top
        new_h = new_box[3] - new_box[1]  # right-left
        #print(size, '|', new_w, new_h, '|', new_box)

        # if too big then exit with previous values
        if new_w > width or new_h > height:
            break

        # set new current values as current values
        font_size = size
        font = new_font
        box = new_box
        w = new_w
        h = new_h

        # calculate position (minus margins in box)
        x = (width - w)//2 - box[0]   # minus left margin
        y = (height - h)//2 - box[1]  # minus top margin

    return font, font_size, box, w, h, x, y

# --- main ---

width = 300
height = 100

text = "World"

font_name = 'Ubuntu-M'

# --- create image for text ---

img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), (200, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# --- calculate font size, box ---

font, font_size, box, w, h, x, y = get_font(img, text, font_name, width, height)

# --- use it ---

print('font size:', font_size)
print('box:', box)

print('w <= width :', w, '<=', width)
print('h <= height:', h, '<=', height)

print('w,h (without margins):', w, h)
print('x,y (without margins):', x, y)

# draw it
draw.text((x, y), text, (0, 0, 0), font)

# display result
img.show()

img.save('result-textbbox.png', 'png')
```